# residue classes and group-theory

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have a question about how I have to do these exercises for my math study

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}, n>0$ and $a \in Z$

a) prove: if $n$ is odd, then $\overline{a} = \overline{(-a)}$ if and only if $\bar{a}$ = $\bar{0}$

b) prove: if $n$ is even, then $\bar{a} = \overline{(-a)}$ if and only if $\bar{a}$ = $\bar{0}$ or $\bar{a}$ = $\overline{\frac{n}{2}}$

For (a), I think I solved a part of the left to right arrow:

$\bar{a}$ =$\overline{(-a)}$ , 
so $n | (a - (-a))$ 
$\Rightarrow n | 2a$

case 1: $n | a$

Also $n | 0$ , hence $a$ and $0$ do both have a remainder of $0$ by division with $n$, so $\bar{a} = \bar{0}$

case 2: $n$ does not divide $a$, 
$n | 2a$, so...(this is where I am stuck)

How to I have to prove the rest of these exercises? I'm trying to do it for 2 days now, but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

For (a): $\bar{a} = \overline {(-a)} \Rightarrow n | 2a \Rightarrow n|a$ (why?)

For(b): First note that we can choose $a < n,$ because using division algorithm we can write $a = nb + r$ for some $b, r \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0 \leq r \leq n-1.$ Then $\bar{a} = \bar{r}.$

So let $a < n$ and also $\bar{a} \neq \bar{0}.$ Now $\bar{a} = \overline {(-a)} \Rightarrow n | 2a \Rightarrow \frac{n}{2}|a \Rightarrow a \leq \frac{n}{2} \Rightarrow 2a = n$

I think you can finish it from here.

Comment: a) That's what I have to prove. If I know that n|a, then it is clear that also holds n|0, hence 0 and a have the same remainder with division by n, and thats it, but why can I say that n|a?

Comment: but $n$ is odd $\Rightarrow$ gcd$(n, 2) = 1.$ so...?

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand a). But I still don't understand b)

Comment: @Peter: I've edited my answer. I hope now it will be clear.

Comment: Sorry, it could be my fault, but I don't see why a < n. What if  a > n or a = n? My teacher gave us a few hints on how to prove this. He said: If n|2a, then qn = 2a (for q on Z). He broke it up in two cases. If q is even, then q = 2k (for k on Z), then a = (2kn)/2 = kn, and for some reason that was a contradiction, so q has to be odd. Then q = 2k + 1.   That was all he said. Maybe you could explain it using this? Thanks in advance

Comment: we can choose $a < n$ because of the division algorithm. as for your hints, $a = kn \Rightarrow \bar{a} = \bar{0}.$ it's not a contradiction unless you start with the assumption $\bar{a} \neq \bar{0}.$ When $q = 2k + 1, 2a = 2kn + n \Rightarrow a = kn + \frac{n}{2} \Rightarrow \bar{a} = \overline{\frac{n}{2}}.$